# How to make "next scene" button one script

Tags: unity-game-engine

When you clear Stage 1, a button is created. Press the button to move to stage 2.
When you clear stage 2, a button is created. Press the button to move to stage 3.
3, then 4, then 5..

Can I make this into one script when moving on to the next scene?

```
SceneManager.LoadScene("Stage2"); // <-- This method requires multiple scripts.
```

Comment: The easiest way is to make a public string for the name of your scene, attach your script to the button and fill in the name of scene it goes to. When handling onClick event you call this loading script

Answer (score 0):

There are probably many ways .. but as AlexeyLarionov said:

Why not have a

```c#
public string targetSceneName;
// or also 
//[SerializeField] private string targetSceneName;
```

configure it in the Inspector and then use

```c#
SceneManager.LoadScene(targetSceneName);
```

You might also be interested in having a [Scene field in the Inspector](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-link-scenes-in-the-inspector.383140/) to make this way easier ;)

---

Alternatively if these anyway are **sequencial levels**  you can also simply go by build index and do e.g.

```c#
SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

A nice solution to this would be to have a `StageManager` class, which holds a `List<string> levels` of your levels by scene name and an `int currentLevel` for the current level. Then your `StageManager` class can have a convenience static method

```
public void LoadNextLevel() 
{
    currentLevel++;;
    string nextLevel = levels[currentLevel];
    SceneManager.LoadScene(nextLevel);
}
```

The convenience of this is that it would be easier to control the scene flow and less dependent on the order of the scenes in your build settings. If you make the `levels` properly `public` or add `[SerializeField]`, you can then easily add new entries to the list and even rearrange them quite simply from the editor. Creating the class in such a way that the method is static would also be very convenient.